# How can I produce a kafka producer in Java

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I'm trying to create a java instance of a Kafka producer which throws this error, but when I run the console producer it works.

I believe the error stems from as the imports

The error:

```
[main] INFO org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser - Kafka version: 2.6.0
[main] INFO org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser - Kafka commitId: 62abe01bee039651
[main] INFO org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser - Kafka startTimeMs: 1602094910199
[kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] ERROR org.apache.kafka.common.utils.KafkaThread - Uncaught exception in thread 'kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1':
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode
    at org.apache.kafka.common.requests.ApiVersionsRequest$Builder.<clinit>(ApiVersionsRequest.java:36)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.handleConnections(NetworkClient.java:910)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:555)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.runOnce(Sender.java:325)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:240)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:602)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    ... 6 more
[main] INFO org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Closing the Kafka producer with timeoutMillis = 9223372036854775807 ms.
```

Comment: The actual code

'''

Comment: Are you using Maven?

Comment: There was someone else with the identical issue: [Error when trying to use kafka-client 2.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64201856/error-when-trying-to-use-kafka-client-2-6#comment113531380_64201856)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using just `kafka-clients` dependency as you can see in the [documentation](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#producerapi)

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
  <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
  <version>2.6.0</version>
</dependency>
```

You should notice that in it's [pom.xml](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/kafka/kafka-clients/2.6.0/kafka-clients-2.6.0.pom) the dependency to `jackson-databind` is marked as `provided`, meaning - it expects/assumes that you'll be running your consumer inside a web container, which most likely has it's own implementation and does not want to interfere.

However, if you're running in a `jvm` that doesn't have `jackson` in classpath already - then just add whatever version you like in your own `pom.xml`

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
  <version>2.10.5</version> <!-- latest? -->
</dependency>
```

( Although it's quite likely that you might need more than that one )

Comment: Thanks this worked I didn't have the Jackson dependency

Comment: @Nyik_nax you're welcome! ( you can also "accept" the answer ;) )